# ClusterProfiler head(GroupGO) shows nothing

Tags: r, bioconductor

Good evening,
i got a weird problem.
First of all i show you the tools i use. There might be the solution but i am not sure

```
library(clusterProfiler)
library(pathview)
library(DOSE)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
```

I am trying to do the normal GO classification. Therefore I used the example commands from http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/clusterProfiler/inst/doc/clusterProfiler.html

```
genenamesSymbol$ab<-c("IFI6","IFNL2","EGR3","FHL3","TNFAIP3","SERTAD2","NR4A3","AKR1C8P","NEK6","TMEM177","CERK","ZNF713","IKZF3","F3","TUBA8","GPNMB","SALL3","SDCCAG3","HIST2H3A","SHANK2","FUNDC2","FAM195A","GPR87","ENO1","LILRA5","NXT1","TRPM2","STX18","ENTHD2","ASPM","RHOV","HIST1H3D","PSTK","NUDT15","ENPEP","TRMU","ZDHHC23","ACAP2","CCL25","ATL3","ADPRM","KRTAP5-11")
```

just an example with some random genes

```
genenames.data.frame <- bitr(genenamesSymbol$ab, fromType = "SYMBOL",
                         toType = c("ENTREZID"),
                         OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db)
gene <- genenames.data.frame[,2]
ggo <- groupGO(gene     = gene,
           OrgDb    = org.Hs.eg.db,
           ont      = "BP",
           level    = 3,
           readable = TRUE)
head(ggo)
barplot(ggo, drop=TRUE, showCategory=12)
```

normaly head(ggo) should show something like this.

```
                   ID                    Description Count GeneRatio
## GO:0005886 GO:0005886                plasma membrane    54    54/207
## GO:0005628 GO:0005628              prospore membrane     0     0/207
## GO:0005789 GO:0005789 endoplasmic reticulum membrane     8     8/207
```

For me it shows an empty table.

```
[1] ID          Description Count       GeneRatio   geneID     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

normally i would expect there went something wrong with giving GroupGO the correct genelist or the genelist itself is empty. But when i do a barplot with ggo it shows me some results. So ggo cant be empty.
I am kind of confused about the problem.

Unfortunately it is important for my Bachelor thesis.
Thats why i hope someone has a solution for me.

thanks for any help or advice,
Julian

Comment: It could be that there is no statistically significant result; have you tested different combinations of argument values (p-value etc.)? You may get different results if you use different packages - e.g. `edgeR`.

Comment: Hey, 
i think there is no p- or q-value (i might be wrong). It just shows me the genratio. For example how many of the genes are connected with negative regulation of metabolic process.